# How to add custom fields to images for image source text and URL

Tags: custom-field, images

How do I add two custom fields to images to allow me to put in text for source name example: Shutterstock
and then link that text to the second custom field URL field example: shutterstock.com

Some solutions out there don't work or are outdated.

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'ac_add_image_source', 10, 2 );

function ac_add_image_source( $form_fields, $post ) {

```
$form_fields['source_name'] = array(
    'label' => __('Source Name'),
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_source_name', true ),
    'helps' => __('Add the name of the image source'),
);

$form_fields['source_url'] = array(
    'label' => __('Source URL'),
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_source_url', true ),
    'helps' => __('Add the URL where the original image was posted'),
);

return $form_fields;
```

}

/**
 * Save credit fields
 * 
 */
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'ac_save_image_source', 10 , 2 );

function ac_save_image_source( $post, $attachment ) {

```
if ( isset( $attachment['source_name'] ) ) {
    $source_name = get_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_source_name', true );
    if ( $source_name != esc_attr( $attachment['source_name'] ) ) {
        if ( empty( $attachment['source_name'] ) )
            delete_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_source_name' );
        else
            update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_source_name', esc_attr( $attachment['source_name'] ) );
    }
}

if ( isset( $attachment['source_url'] ) ) {
    $source_name = get_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_source_url', true );
    if ( $source_name != esc_attr( $attachment['source_url'] ) ) {
        if ( empty( $attachment['source_url'] ) )
            delete_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_source_url' );
        else
            update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_source_url', esc_attr( $attachment['source_url'] ) );
    }
}

return $post;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you could achieve this.

The most obvious one would be to use two existing image fields- are you already using Title, caption, alt text and description?  If not, these are available, and you could simply add some code to your template to use (say) the caption as the link and the description as the source.

If this seems messy or if you are already using the image fields, you could also use a plugin to make categories available to media items. I recently used this one with some success:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-media-library-categories/

With the addition of a couple of lines of code, this lets you store image categories separately from ordinary post categories:

```
/**
* separate media categories from post categories
* use a custom category called 'category_media' for the categories in the media library
*/
add_filter( 'wpmediacategory_taxonomy', function(){ return 'category_media'; } );
```

This way you could store the sources as media categories, putting the URL in the category description field. The advantage of this approach would be that you'd be able to globally change source URLs without changing individual image data.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

The functions.php hook you found is working just fine. To output the values it's storing, you just need to pass the ID of the image to the get_post_meta function along with the keys for the values stored. In the snippet below I'm assuming the image is the thumbnail of the current post.

```
$source_url = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'_wp_attachment_source_url', true);
$source_name = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'_wp_attachment_source_name', true); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $source_url; ?>"><?php echo $source_name; ?></a>
```

Let me know if you have any trouble.

**EDIT 2**

In response to the original poster's request, here is a filter to incorporate the newly stored source information into images inserted via the WordPress editor. This function and filter need to be put in the functions.php file as well. This checks that both a link and source name exist. If they do, it outputs a line break and a link to the source, opening in a new window.

```
function image_add_caption_with_source( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ) {

  /**
   * Filters the caption text and adds source info.
   *
   * Note: If the caption text is empty, the caption shortcode will not be appended
   * to the image HTML when inserted into the editor.
   *
   * Passing an empty value also prevents the {@see 'image_add_caption_shortcode'}
   * Filters from being evaluated at the end of image_add_caption().
   *
   * @since 4.1.0
   *
   * @param string $caption The original caption text.
   * @param int    $id      The attachment ID.
   */
  $caption = apply_filters( 'image_add_caption_text', $caption, $id );
  $source_url = get_post_meta($id,'_wp_attachment_source_url', true);
  $source_name = get_post_meta($id,'_wp_attachment_source_name', true);
  /**
   * Filters whether to disable captions.
   *
   * Prevents image captions from being appended to image HTML when inserted into the editor.
   *
   * @since 2.6.0
   *
   * @param bool $bool Whether to disable appending captions. Returning true to the filter
   *                   will disable captions. Default empty string.
   */
  if ( empty($caption) || apply_filters( 'disable_captions', '' ) )
    return $html;

  $id = ( 0 < (int) $id ) ? 'attachment_' . $id : '';

  if ( ! preg_match( '/width=["\']([0-9]+)/', $html, $matches ) )
    return $html;

  $width = $matches[1];

  $caption = str_replace( array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $caption);
  $caption = preg_replace_callback( '/<[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [^<>]+>)*/', '_cleanup_image_add_caption', $caption );

  // Convert any remaining line breaks to <br>.
  $caption = preg_replace( '/[ \n\t]*\n[ \t]*/', '<br />', $caption );

  $html = preg_replace( '/(class=["\'][^\'"]*)align(none|left|right|center)\s?/', '$1', $html );
  if($source_url && $source_name):
   $source ='<br /><a target="_blank" href="'.$source_url.'">'.$source_name.'</a>';
  else:
   $source = "";
  endif;
  if ( empty($align) )
    $align = 'none';

  $shcode = '[caption id="' . $id . '" align="align' . $align . '" width="' . $width . '"]' . $html . ' ' . $caption . $source . '[/caption]';

  /**
   * Filters the image HTML markup including the caption shortcode.
   *
   * @since 2.6.0
   *
   * @param string $shcode The image HTML markup with caption shortcode.
   * @param string $html   The image HTML markup.
   */

  return apply_filters( 'image_add_caption_shortcode', $shcode, $html );
}


// remove the existing filter
remove_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'image_add_caption', 20, 8 );
// add the new filter
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'image_add_caption_with_source', 20, 8 );
```

Comment: Hi Jonny,
I use all the tabs for my images so would need two extra fields added.
The above link i mentioned does do this but when i actually put text and url into the fields it shows nothing on frontend.
Also don't need to put my images into categories as each image has a different source.

Comment: I just noticed someone edited the link out from my main post so I added the code there instead. It put it into two separate boxes but it is all just one code

Comment: Do you know if that code above is successfully saving what you type in into the database?

Comment: I am not sure do you have a site you could quickly try it on? Just paste into functions.php

Comment: Sure. It seems to work (ie display the admin form and store the data) - it's just that the snippet you found didn't specify how to output the stored values. I am adding info about that to my answer above.

Comment: Hi Jonny,
So I place the code that I posted in the beginning in my functions.php and also copy and paste the code you put in your edit in my functions.php under the other code?

This is for images that go in blog posts. So say a blog post has 5 images and each image has its own source this should all work correctly right?

Comment: Hi.  No, the snippet I just gave you is for the template where you're outputting the images (separate from the code you had correctly placed in your functions.php).  If you're just inserting the images manually using the wordpress editor, you will need an additional filter to include and format the source information.  Are you looking for it just to be included in the caption?

Comment: Yeah that is correct in the caption.
So for example, lets say I got an image from shutterstock
When I upload the media and put it in a blog post I want the caption under the image to show the test ''Shutterstock'' and have it link to say ''shutterstock.com''. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Are you able to answer this Jonny?

Comment: Hi. I did have a go but couldn't get it working locally! Shouldn't be hard - we essentially just have to overwrite the core function 'img_caption_shortcode' in functions.php and have it include the new fields.  I'll have another go and let you know.

Comment: OK I have it.  Will update answer above.

Comment: Hi Jonny,
So do I need to still use that original code I pasted above? and put it in functions.php followed by your edit 2 code?

Comment: That's correct. So the code you originally got adds in the hooks to store the two fields, and the code I've just put together for you adds in the hooks to add the link and name into the caption.

Comment: How did that work for you?

Comment: Didn't do anything which is strange! I will keep trying though

Comment: Hmm!  Feel free to post something somewhere. This very code definitely did it for me using the latest WP and the regular 'add media' button above the post area to insert.